# what does this error code tell me?

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

My software produced following error on a computer that had no debugger. I've been only sent the error message, and all I am able to understand is that somewhen a function called a get Item on a datagridview with a index that was too big. also this function has been called by a timer... Is there a way to find out somehow what datagrid? what function? or whatever can help me to find the cause? The software was obfuscated..

```
   ************** Testo dell'eccezione **************

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index non compreso nell'intervallo. Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta.
Nome parametro: index
   in System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
   in System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   in bU?Fr_;Iv^$tpm3^/!sU0<HH".(DataGridViewRowCollection , Int32 )
   in bU?Fr_;Iv^$tpm3^/!sU0<HH".(Int32 )
   in bU?Fr_;Iv^$tpm3^/!sU0<HH".(Object , EventArgs )
   in System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to get instance information without you adding logging to the application.  You could log which DataGrid is being used when it crashes.

Edit:
You can log with anything from a simple WriteLine to a text file, all the way to a full .NET based logging library (plenty on github).

`what function?`

The method that you should be looking at is

`in bU?Fr_;Iv^$tpm3^/!sU0<HH".(Object , EventArgs )`

You can either figure out which method that is in real code, or your obfuscator should have a map of the real class/method name to the obfuscated name.

Comment: how could I log that? with "what function" i mean the sub routine or function that caused the error to show up.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Jim W said, you can log errors using the following:

```
Public Sub addLog(txt As String)
    logFile = "location/to/store/file.log"
    Dim dateTime As String = "[" + System.DateTime.Now + "]"
    Dim logStore As String = ""
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(logFile) Then
        logStore = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(location)
    Else
        File.Create(logFile).Dispose()
    End If
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(logFile,
    dateTime + vbNewLine + txt + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + logStore, False)
End Sub
```

You can access it as follows:

```
Try
    ''code to try
Catch ex As Exception
    addLog(ex.ToString)
End Try
```